# Get doc file property in PS

Tags: powershell

I want to find all .doc files on my notebook, and to remove field author in all of them, how can i get author field in powershell, get-itemproperty cant give this

```
$file = Get-ItemProperty -Path test.doc
```

Comment: I don't see a property "author" or anything similar when retrieving properties from a word file. For me: Get-ItemProperty -Path C:\path\way\doc.docx | select *

Comment: See this scripting guy article on getting author and other properties from a doc/docx file. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/02/use-powershell-to-find-specific-word-built-in-properties/